# C# Constructors and Contexes

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a console application that converts centimeters to meters
Here are my objectives

1. Store number of centimeters entered in an attribute
2. Use a default constructor to store zero in the attribute that stores the number of centimeters meters entered
3. Use a primary constructor to accept and store number of centimeters entered.
4. A function call getMeters to return the number of meters
5. A function called Remainder to get the number of centimeter remanding after conversion
6. A function called Printout that will display the results

The application should carry on accepting values for conversion until the user decides to end it.

What I have so far:

```
using System;

namespace Conv
{

public class Centimeter
{
    public int cmvar;
    public Centimeter()
    {
        cmvar = 0;
    }
}

//primary const to be added


public class MeterToCenti
{
    public static void Main()
    {
           char choice;
           char n = 'n';

           do
           {
           Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? (y/n)");
           //choice = Console.ReadLine();
           choice = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
           Centimeter c = new Centimeter();
           Console.WriteLine("enter value in centimeters");
           c.cmvar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
           Printout();
           }
           while(choice.CompareTo(n) == 0);
    }


public static void getMeterst()
    {
    int meters = c.cmvar / 100;
    }


public static void Remainder ()
    {
        int cmremain = c.cmvar % 100;
    }


public static void Printout()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Meters and {1} Centimeters", meters, cmremain);
    }

}


}
```

I am getting errors regarding:

```
    prog.cs(24,5): warning CS0168: The variable `meters' is declared but never used
prog.cs(41,11): error CS0103: The name `c' does not exist in the current context
prog.cs(41,2): error CS0103: The name `meters' does not exist in the current context
prog.cs(47,24): error CS0103: The name `c' does not exist in the current context
prog.cs(53,61): error CS0103: The name `meters' does not exist in the current context
prog.cs(53,69): error CS0103: The name `cmremain' does not exist in the current contex
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you make up your mind which version of C# you're using? There is a massive difference between C# 2.0 and C# 5.0...

Comment: Those errors are very straight foreward, and tell you EXACTLY what is wrong and where. You should read them.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn the art of debugging.  And the concept of variable scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've got a lot of issues with scope in your code, when you declare something, it can (as a rule) only be accessed inside whatever set of brackets you declare it in, so when you try and access `c` and `cmremain`and things like that without specifying their location or accessing them correctly you get errors like this.

I have working code below, but feel free to ask any extra questions as to 'why' this works.

```
using System;

namespace Conv
{

public class Centimeter
{
    public int cmvar;
    public Centimeter()
    {
        cmvar = 0;
    }
}

//primary const to be added


public class MeterToCenti
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        char choice;
        char n = 'n';

        do
        {
            Centimeter c = new Centimeter();
            Console.WriteLine("enter value in centimeters");
            c.cmvar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Printout(c);
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? (y/n)");
            choice = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        while (choice != n);
    }


public static int getMeters(Centimeter c)
    {
        int meters = c.cmvar / 100;
        return meters;
    }


public static int Remainder(Centimeter c)
    {
        int cmremain = c.cmvar % 100;
        return cmremain;
    }


public static void Printout(Centimeter c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Meters and {1} Centimeters", getMeters(c), Remainder(c));
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Thanks @ConnorLSW. My understanding of OOP is lacking. I am learning, however I have understood what you have written here. My question is, how do i incorporate the default constructor that will store 0 in the variable? Also, the primary constructor? I realize it doesnt work as I would expect i.e when the user doesn't enter a value, the code fails with: **Input string was not in the correct format**

Comment: you can use `Int.TryParse()` to make sure the user enters the number correctly. and `cmvar = 0` is the default constructor for that variable since you only access it through your `centimeter` object, `int cmvar = 0` would be the default constructor normally, but is more or less needless here due to your layout :)

Answer (score 5):

In some programming languages, a context is usually defined by `{` and `}`, meaning that given this:

```
{
    int a = ...
}
```

`a` exists specifically within that block. Assuming that no other variable named `a` has been declared outside the braces, doing something like so:

```
{
    int a = ...
}
print(a)
```

Will result in a fault, since `a` no longer exists.

In your case for instance, you are declaring the following variable: `Centimeter c = new Centimeter();`. Notice that this is enclosed within the `do...while` scope, so it exists only in there. Thus, when you try to access your variable from another method, which has its own *scope*, you get the exception you are getting.

To start solving the issue, you should move the 3 methods `getMeterst`, `Remainder` and `Printout` in their appropriate class, which is `Centimeter`.

I would recommend you start by looking at some tutorials, since you have other issues with your code.

---

As pointed out by @user2864740, different languages treat scopes differently. Taking Javascript in consideration:

```
        function hello()
        {
            {
                var i = 44;
            }
            {
                alert(i);
            }
        }
```

Yields an alert with the value of 44.

However, the code below does not compile in C#:

```
    private static void Hello()
    {
        {
            int i = 0;
        }
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);    //The name i does not exist in the current context.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to learn oriented object programming before programming any oop language.
Basic is good but polute your mind by not thinking object, but sequencial...

Here is your code fixed

```
using System;
namespace Conv
{
    public class Centimeter
    {
        public int cmvar;
        public Centimeter()
        {
            cmvar = 0;
        }
        public Centimeter(int mm)
        {
            cmvar = mm;
        }
        public int getMeterst()
        {
            return cmvar / 100;
        }
        public int Remainder()
        {
            return cmvar % 100;
        }
        public void Printout()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Meters and {1} Centimeters", this.getMeterst(), this.Remainder());
        }
    }
    public class MeterToCenti
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            char choice;
            char n = 'n';
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? (y/n)");
                choice = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                Console.WriteLine(); // for pure design needs
                Centimeter c = new Centimeter();
                Console.WriteLine("enter value in centimeters");
                c.cmvar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                c.Printout();
            }
            while (choice != n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Xavius Pupuss. My understanding of OOP is lacking. I am learning, however I have understood what you have written here as well. My question is, how do i incorporate the default constructor that will store 0 in the variable? Also, the primary constructor? I realize it doesnt work as I would expect i.e when the user doesn't enter a value, the code fails with: **Input string was not in the correct format**